# Determinant of a matrix having entries as a rational function of the row and column indices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Is there a method to find an expression for the determinant of an order $n$ matrix with entries that are a rational function of the row and column indices?

For a specific example, I'm looking for an expression for the determinant of a matrix of size $n \times n$ with $(i,j)$th entry

$a_{i,j} = \frac{i+j} {i+j+1}$

For $n = 3$, this is $\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1/2 & 2/3 \\ 
1/2 & 2/3 & 3/4 \\ 
2/3 & 3/4 & 4/5  \notag
\end{vmatrix}$ = $-1/252$.

Comment: Every matrix has this form, for fixed $n$. Your question is really about what happens when $n$ varies but the rarional function stays the same.

Comment: You might want to note that your numbering of rows and columns starts with $i,j=0$, which is more common in programming than in math.

Comment: A matrix whose entries are (as above) a function of $i+j$ is said to be a Hankel matrix.  There are fast algorithms for the determinant of a Hankel matrix.

Comment: Your "specific example" is closely related to the [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix), whose determinant has an explicit formula (though not especially easy to evaluate).  In fact your example is a "rank one" update to the Hilbert matrix and can be evaluated explicitly in this connection.